# How to logout with mod_auth_openidc

Tags: apache, logout, mod-auth-openidc

I use mod_auth_openidc to implement login on my website. I use multiple providers, so to initiate a login into one I redirect to:
`/protected/redirect_uri/?target_link_uri=<urlencoded protected location>&iss=<urlencoded issuer>`
which works as expected.
Now I want to initiate a logout in a similar manner, by refering the logout button to:
`/protected/redirect_uri?logout=<urlencoded logoutpage>&iss=<urlencoded issuer>`
but I simply get a 404. Of course `/protected/redirect_uri` does not actually exist but for some reson openidc does not handle the logout request.
The logout page is not protected and the provider has an `end_session_endpoint` in it's metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the slash at the end of the redirect URI matters, if it is not there the request will not be considered as matching

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: Note that you can define `OIDCRedirectURI` without a trailing slash and in that case requests with a trailing slash will fail.